# SCSS file served via webpack dev server is different than source

Tags: webpack, sass

So basically I use webpack, to compile sass files.

Here is the dev config:

https://pastebin.com/HqqU1szG

My problem is, that when i have SCSS written like so:

`.something {
  color: red;
}`

What gets served in my browser web tools looks like so:

```
.something {
  color:red;}
```

As a consequence, when I inspect `.something`, in my browser (or rather something that matches rule further down in css file, the line number reported in dev tools does not match.

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Use source maps. If all lines are staying where they were, you don't need webpack in the first place, so the fact that lines aren't corresponding is perfectly normal. Now, if lines are _not_ staying where they were, source maps will tell developer tools where to find the original lines. Use source maps.

Comment: I am using source maps. But for some reason, as I stated chrome or webpack (i am not sure) reformats my SCSS in different style, therefore throwing off the line numbers

Comment: Not sure, I think [`fast-sass-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-sass-loader#vs-sass-loader) doesn't support source maps.